# Unwrap examples in Rd files

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2, rd

I've recently submitted a package to CRAN, and one of their comments was "Please unwrap all examples in your Rd-files that can be executed in less than 5 sec per Rd-files".

I generate those rd files with roxygen2, so I'm not really sure what do they exactly mean by unwrapping all the examples. All of them have a don't run argument, so I'm not sure if that's what I have to remove. Below there's some sample code.

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/netDir.R
\name{make.netDir}
\alias{make.netDir}
\title{Directed network}
\usage{
make.netDir(x, disp = FALSE, cap = FALSE, alpha = 0.003, pct = 10,
  carrier = FALSE, metro = FALSE)
}
\arguments{
\item{x}{Data frame}

\item{disp}{Uses the Serrano's disparity filter (\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disparity_filter_algorithm_of_weighted_network})
to extract the backbone of the network.}

\item{cap}{Filters original data based on the edge weight.}

\item{alpha}{Argument for disparity filter.}

\item{pct}{Argument for cap filter. Value should be imput as percentage.}

\item{carrier}{Groups data per carrier and OD}

\item{metro}{Groups data by metropolitan area (not compatible with plot)}
}
\description{
Generates Directed Network with an iGraph object and a Data Frame.
}
\examples{
\dontrun{
make.netDir(OD_sample)

# Apply Disparity Filter
make.netDir(OD_sample, disp = TRUE, alpha = 0.05)

# Apply Percentage Cap
make.netDir(OD_sample, cap = TRUE, pct = 20)
}
}
```

EDIT: The package got into CRAN, meaning that it passed all the tests, and remarks and so on. However, I still got the comments mentioned above.

Comment: maybe you need to have some examples (which takes less than 5seconds) to be run during `R CMD check`. i presume you have zero examples being run right now.

Comment: So basically to just remove the `\dontrun{}` argument and make sure that they take the time they specified. I just don't really understand why is there a need of having a runnable example when they don't specify that in their policies.

Comment: > from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html: In principle, packages must pass R CMD check without warnings or significant notes to be admitted to the main CRAN package area. If there are warnings or notes you cannot eliminate (for example because you believe them to be spurious) send an explanatory note as part of your covering email, or as a comment on the submission form.

Comment: @chinsoon12, and it passed, otherwise it wouldn't be published there. 0 warnings and 0 notes. I'll ask then again on my next submission.
I just asked here because I wanted to avoid to have to resubmit in case they get me back on this.
It could be that someone had the same experience.

Comment: Packages are supposed to have executable examples/tests. If you have none and also no tests, you may get a `NOTE`.

Comment: @Thomas, as I've mentioned above, the package got into CRAN. It has been accepted and published. Meaning that it does have all the necessary tests, the examples are executable, and that I have 0 notes and 0 warnings.
The only thing I do have, is that I force a \dontrun argument on the examples due to the package characteristics.

Comment: Right. My comment is that CRAN can interpret a package that has no executable examples and no tests as one that is not release-ready, even if it passes R CMD check. When they say "unwrap", they mean that they want some of your examples executable (i.e., not in `\dontrun{}`) as proof that your package actually works. This is not a requirement, but a preference I have heard from them before.